# Problem running several programs or commands at the same time

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, executable, parallelism

I had a problem because I have to execute near 1700 times the same program with different data. That program do several calculations using iterations, and the answer is obtained 5 hours later aproximatly. The problem is this morning I have created a bash script that moves through the different directories and executes the program using `nohup ./name_of_the-program >1&`, but when I have run it, my server was collapsed with these commands and I had to restart it manually (I tought that them were executed when others finisehd). How can I run it? I have the possibility of use 3 differente linux servers, in which I can run 16, 16 and 20 at the sem time.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you think `>1&` does? `&` runs the command in the background and does not wait for it to finish.

Comment: We need to know far more about the process. You won't want to swap, so how much RAM does one calculation take, and what is the total free RAM? That could be more limiting than number of processes or CPU time. Also, does *each* of your 1700 calculations run CPU-limited for 5 hours? If you can use your 52 CPUs with 100% effect, that runs for a week. You may need to rent a CPU cluster, or use `parallel`, or find a better algorithm for the process.

Comment: `>1&` sends _stdout_ to the file called `1`, running the program in the background. I'm not entirely sure that's what you intend

Comment: My problem was when I execute 1600 times `nohup ./name_of_the-program >1&` my computer was collapsed and I couldn't connect remotely (I had to power off it manually to restart it and eliminate active process)

Comment: Your server can not cope with 1600+ instances of the same program running at the same time, you have created something with the same effect as a [Fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).  Use `xargs -P` or GNU `parallel` to limit the number of simultaneous jobs (1 per CPU core or thread is good if the task is primarily CPU-bound and you have enough RAM to run that many jobs simultaneously.  Significantly less if it's primarily I/O-bound - i.e. each job reads/writes a lot of data from disk or network).

Comment: if you have three servers (and they aren't already set up as a cluster with slurm or torque or similar) with 16, 16, and 20 cores/threads respectively then split the data between the three servers and run 16, 16, 20 jobs on them. e.g. If they all have access to the same file server, split them into three sub-directories (but remember that network I/O is a limited shared resource). Alternatively copy a third of the data to each of the three servers so they can each run with their local subset of the data files.

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel is built for this kind of thing.

Start `tmux` on one server:

```
tmux
```

Make sure you can `ssh` to server1, server2, and server3.

Then run:

```
cat 1700_arguments |
  parallel --dry-run --joblog my.log -S server1,server2,server3 name_of_the-program
```

When the commands to run look right, remove `--dry-run`.

Then disconnect from the server (use `tmux at` to re-connect).

With the `--joblog` you will be able to resume or re-run failing jobs.

To get to the correct dir, you may want to use `--wd .`.